# App crashes on the request of access token

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, authlib

I am trying to get the access token using my authorization code:

```
curl --basic --user "{client_id}:{client_secret}" -X POST -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&state={state}" http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/token
```

I passed **state** parameter when I requested the authorization code:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={client_id}&state={state}
```

But my auth service responses:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

I checked execution in the debug mode, Authlib is trying to get **state** key in `OAuthRequest` but can't find it.
I can't get what am I doing wrong?

Routes:

```
@bp.route("/oauth/authorize", methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def authorize():
    user = current_user()
    return server.create_authorization_response(grant_user=user)


@bp.route('/oauth/token', methods=['POST'])
def issue_token():
    return server.create_token_response()
```

Comment: There is no state when getting access token.

Comment: But if it crashes, it should be a bug.

Comment: @lepture, in docs it has... But it doesn't matter because at first I tried without **state** parameter and had same bug.

Comment: You need to show us the error stack instead of the 500 error.